# Equivalent of Angular 1 otherwise route in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I'm using Angular 2 routing for my application and it works pretty well but I have no idea how to define the "otherwise" route. So a route that will be displayed if none if the current URL does not correspond to any "supported" route.

Here is an example of my current configuration:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: StoryComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/story', name: 'Story', component: StoryComponent },
    { path: '/subscription', name: 'Subscription', component: SubscriptionComponent}
])
```

Comment: That feature is not yet implemented, check [#2965](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2965) and [#4055](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4055)

Comment: Isn't that why you have the 'useAsDefault' ?

Answer (score 10):

This hasn't currently been implemented in angular 2. The best current solution is to use a solution like @Gary showed.

```
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

as shown in the angular guide routing section(https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

Answer (score 8):

There is no 'otherwise' route in angular 2 yet. But the same functionality can be achieved using wildcard parameter, like so:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', redirectTo: ['Home'] },
    { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
    // all other routes and finally at the last add
    {path: '/*path', component: NotFound}
```

This will only load the 'NotFound' component and the url will be same as what you navigate to. In case you want all not matching routes to redirect to a '404' url, you can do something like:

```
//at the end of the route definitions
{ path: '/404', name: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
{ path: '/*path', redirectTo:['404'] }`
```

Comment: The redirect does not work, if you're redirecting to a subroute. I would suggest just using the `NotFound` component and injecting the `Router`, so you can redirect inside the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead of otherwise. It works for me, not sure but seems like work in progress.

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/**', redirectTo: ['MycmpnameCmp'] }, 
   ...
  }
])
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4055

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    // all other routes
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'edit-event', component: EventComponent },
    { path: 'participants', component: ParticipantsComponent },
    { path: 'notification', component: NotificationComponent },
    { path: '', component: WelcomeComponent }, //default
    { path: '**', component: WelcomeComponent } //page not found route
], { useHash: true })
```

useHash parameter is for using hash url style
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-config