# Angular 2 Router Directly Accessing URL

Tags: routes, angular

I have my `main.component.ts` code:
Its location is: `root/`

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnChanges, IterableDiffers} from 'angular2/core';
import {TypeService} from './type/type.service';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    providers: [],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
      <a [routerLink]="['Type']">Type</a>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/type', name: 'Type', component: TypeService}
])

export class AppComponent{
  constructor(private _router: Router){}
}
```

Then I have my `type.component.ts` code:
Its location is: `root/type`

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {DirectoryComponent} from '../main/main.component';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'type',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `<h1>hi</h1>`
})

export class TypeService{

  constructor(
    private _router: Router) {}
  }
```

When I click the Type link in my main application it takes me to root/type and it loads the type component. However if I press reload it gives me a Not Found error.

How do I make it so I can access components directly via the url?

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure your server to serve your main file (usually `index.html`) when it cannot find requested url. Depending on what server you're using it could be `.htaccess` file, middleware, routing configuration etc. There are many similar questions on SO, try to find answer for your specific case...

Comment: is there a thing like otherwise like in angular 1.x?

Comment: @Gary I'm using `{ path: '/:unknown', redirectTo: ['/Root'] }`, not sure if there's a better way...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34381438/equivalent-of-angular-1-otherwise-route-in-angular-2 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4055 Let me answer this formally. Stumbled on this issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

I used the HashLocationStrategy to fix it.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/HashLocationStrategy-class.html

In main.ts:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  LocationStrategy,
  HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

Then going to root/#/type it takes me to my type component.

Comment: Try this instead of otherwise. It works for me, not sure but seems like work in progress.

`@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/**', redirectTo: ['MycmpnameCmp'] }, 
   ...
  }
])`
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4055